# Sonarqube hangs on start (jruby.rack related?)

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar can never get past the following line in the sonar.log

```
2014.06.23 17:59:50 INFO  [jruby.rack]  jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_60-b19 [linux-amd64]
2014.06.23 17:59:50 INFO  [jruby.rack]  using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2014.06.23 18:00:08 INFO  [jruby.rack]  keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
```

There are no exceptions in the log, it connected to the database via hibernate correctly, no issues as far as I can tell.  I've even gone so far as to a) drop and recreate the database b) restart machine c) delete and reinstall the software

I've left sonar running 20+ minutes with no change in the log.  Connecting via the browser just times out.

Comment: So it finally came back with the following:: 2014.06.23 18:36:38 INFO  [o.a.c.u.SessionIdGenerator]  Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [601,837] milliseconds.